# Can I use an SDF as a plant for DirectCollocation?

Tags: drake

My goal is to use an SDF I made that models a cart-pole system and use `DirectCollocation` to find a swing-up trajectory.

However, when I try to use the plant created by the SDF and use `DirectCollocation` to construct the mathematical program I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: This system doesn't have any continuous states. DirectCollocation only makes sense for systems with continuous-time dynamics.`

Can an SDF create a continuous system or am I required to create my own LeafSystem?

I've been using **Example: 10.2 Direct Collocation for the Pendulum, Acrobot, and Cart-Pole** as a reference from the Underactuated Book as well as digging through `drake/examples/acrobot`. Any additional reference suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that you have explicitly constructed a *discrete* MultibodyPlant. Take a look at the [constructor](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a3296be9fa9bc35e6639460f54029c4c9) documentation. If you construct it as continuous (e.g., `time_step = 0`), then you can parse your SDF into it.

You can confirm this by looking at your construction of the plant and confirm that you're passing a non-zero time step.